# Looping through an array of objects, calling a promise for every object and logging when it's complete

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

In this problem I am trying to loop through an array of objects retrieved from a promise, and for every object in the array I want 
to call another promise. Once I have called all of those promises I want to log DONE to the console.

How can I tell when all the promises have completed?

```js
function myFunction() {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums").then(first_response => {
    first_response.json().then(function(value) {
      for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
          .then(second_response => second_response.json())
          .then(value => console.log(value))
      }
      console.log("DONE!!");
    });
  });
}

myFunction();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.map` to turn the `value` array into an array of Promises, and call `.then` on the `Promise.all` of that array. You should also avoid the Promise-as-callback antipattern, just `return` the Promise from one `.then` to chain it to the next `.then`, without creating unnecessary nesting:

```
function myFunction () {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums")
    .then(first_response => first_response.json())
    .then(arr => Promise.all(arr.map(item => 
       fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
       .then(second_response => second_response.json())
       .then(value => console.log(value))
      )))
    .then(() => {
      console.log("DONE!!");      
    });
}

myFunction();
```

Note that your current code doesn't appear to use anything in the first response except the length of the resulting array, which is pretty weird - if you want to use the item you're iterating over (to create the new URL to fetch, for example), use the `item` variable in the mapping function above.

Comment: thank you, yes. It is weird, it is part of a bigger problem that I just need help with. In reality I'll be passing values to the loop.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If so, consider upvoting and accepting one of them, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect the promises in an array and use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in order to provide a callback when all are completed. The easiest way to do that is to change your `for` loop into a call to [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
function myFunction() {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums").then(first_response => {
    return first_response.json();
  }).then(function(value) {
    const promises = value.map((_, i) => {
      return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        .then(second_response => second_response.json())
        .then(value => console.log(value))
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
  }).then(() => console.log("DONE!!"));
}

myFunction();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use es6 feature promises feature to get all your fetch request together and if all promises complete then you can print done.

```
    function myFunction () {
  var promises = [];
  var promise = undefined;
   fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums").then(first_response => {
       first_response.json().then(function(value) {
            for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++){
              promise = fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/?id="+value[i].id)
                  .then(second_response => second_response.json())
                  .then(value => console.log(value))   
              promises.push(promise)
            }
        Promise.all(promises).then(function(){ console.log("Done!");});
       });
   });
}
```

https://codepen.io/Shajith/pen/vPGGPJ?editors=0010